# Anti-Aliasing and Moiré Patterns in Export

Tags: plotting, export, antialiasing, cuda

I export a lot of plot expressions with `Export["filename.pdf",graphicsexpr]` and would like to prevent aliasing and Moiré patterns in the .pdf file. Anything from the image manipulation suite of features or custom-CUDA welcome, I am well prepared for CUDA programming.

I am aware that the rules expect the poster to show that he made at least some initial attempt, but I have no idea where to start with this, other than to search the web for some .pdf post-processing application.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of a plot export where the problem is obvious?

Comment: ListLinePlot[(-1)^#&/@Range[100],PlotStyle->Black] or ListLinePlot[(-1)^#&/@Range[200],PlotStyle->Black]. On a 1920x1080 screen this looks terrible.

Comment: You can reduce the effect by using thinner lines and using a shade of Gray rather than Black, e.g., `PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[0.1], GrayLevel[.5]]`

Comment: I had already tried that, also with AbsoluteThickness[1/10], but that didn't help. And for the print (on actual paper) this needs to be black, not gray.